# Search for a word in elements of list, and copy the whole element string and print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I do have a list (Got by reading a file line by line):

```
['agadfad\n', 'sdffasdf\n', 'Element 1, 0, 0, 0\n', 'Pcom\n', 'Element 2\n']
```

I want to search for "Element 1" in the whole list, and if found the whole string should be printed which is "Element 1, 0, 0, 0". I tried the following:

```
#File Reading
itr = 0 
elem = ''
path1 = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\BDF1.TXT"
text1 = ' '
with open(path1) as file1:
    lines = file1.readlines()
print lines
#letters = set('Element 1')
#for line in lines:
if any('Element 1' in text1 for text1 in lines):
    print text1 
        #if letters & set(line):
        #    print line            
        #text = re.match("(E\w+)\W(\w+)",line)
        #if text:
        #    print text.group()
        #else:
        #    print "No Match Found"
    #print line.split(",") 
    #if line.split(',') == 'Element 1':
    #    print "Match Found"
    #text = line.split(',')
    #print text
#for line in file1:
#    itr = itr + 1
#    line = file1.readline()
#    print line
#data = file1.read()
#print data
file1.close()
```

I want to do this because further i want to search the string in a different file and if found replace the whole line with the new one which is again "Element 1, 0, 0, 0".

But upto now i am just able to print "Element 1"  which is search keyword.

Comment: So what's your issue here?

Comment: @IronFist My issue is i am unable to print the whole string "Element 1,0,0,0". I am only able to print Element 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text1` is a local variable to `any()` so you can not reference it outside `any()`, instead loop through `lines` and `print` the match:

```
target = 'Element 1'
for line in lines:
    if target in line:
        print line
        break #exit from loop
```

A better approach is to loop through the file object when you read your input file and check if `Element 1` s in one of the lines then print it, without the need to read the whole lines and loop through them again, this way:

```
target = 'Element 1'
with open(path1) as file1:
    for line in file1:
        if target in line:
            print line
            break
```

Comment: Thanks @Iron, but what i want is basically to use that same line, search in another file as "Element 1" if found want to replace with data as present in this file which is "Element 1, 0, 0, 0" in that other file (in which i want to search).

Comment: Then you have to open the second file and then while iterating and if `Element 1` is found in both files, then `write` that `line` in the second file...if I have understood you well

Answer (score 0):

String is a sequence, so you can use a `in` operator with it. But you can't compare with list because 'Element 1' isn't a member of the list, but a member of a element in the list.

So you can try:

```
for item in lines:
    if 'Element 1' in item:
        print(item)
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
for item in [x for x in lines if 'Element 1' in x]:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have doesn't match the logic you want. The condition

```
if any('Element 1' in text1 for text1 in lines):
```

just says, "if any element in the list meets the condition." What you want to do is check *each element individually*, and then take action on each result.

You have a couple options.

First, you could collect all the results you want by first filtering the list to elements matching the condition. Then you can process the resulting list. Like this:

```
matching_lines = [l for l in lines if 'Element 1' in l]
for l in matching_lines:
    print(l)
```

This is better if you generally need to work with the entire result set as a whole, since it saves the results for later processing.

Second, if you don't want to learn about generators or list comprehensions right now or if you don't need the results saved for later, then you can use a simple `for` loop with an `if` statement inside:

```
for l in lines:
   if 'Element 1' in l:
       print(l)
```

If the file has a large number of lines (thousands or more), this could save memory and potentially be faster if you don't need the results later. That does **not** appear to be your use case, though, since you load the entire file into memory earlier.

Comment: Yeah, but what i want is keeping one file open, reading a line from it, searching in second file as per specific keyword, if found, want to replace data with the line present in first file.

Comment: @Divyanshu Well, your code doesn't open a second file. Nor does it attempt to compare the two. If that's your question, then your question is too broad. (It would basically be a, "Write my code for me," question at that point.) I would accept one of the answers here and then try to go a little further along in the logic, if I were you. (It doesn't have to be mine, especially if one of the others ends up working better for what you want to do.)

Comment: Yes, i am trying at my own with your help and comments. I want to thank you. I just was trying to clarify what is my ultimate goal.